# How to visualize the result of pcl::FPFHEstimation in point cloud using PCL?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, feature-detection

I'm using pcl::FPFHEstimation class to detect feature point like this:

```
pcl::FPFHEstimationOMP<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::FPFHSignature33> fest;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33>::Ptr object_features(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33>());
fest.setRadiusSearch(feature_radius);
fest.setInputCloud(source_cloud);
fest.setInputNormals(point_normal);
fest.compute(*object_features);
```

My question is how to visulize detected feature points in pointcloud? like detected feature points in red color and non-feature points in white color.

I have searched a lot for this, but I only find some ways to display histogram which is not what I want.

Comment: The algorithm will compute the fast point feature histogram for all points in your cloud, so you would have to paint all the cloud the same color.

Comment: @apalomer You mean this algorithm won't distinguish feature point and non-feature point ?

Comment: No, the algorithm compute the feature for all the points in the cloud. This will give you a descriptor for each point in the cloud. Once you have the descriptors you are the one that needs to distinguish what is for you a relevant point (key point) and what is not. [Here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5152473) yo can find the algorithm explained and [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/rob.21907) a paper where I use this as a feature to associate point clouds for registration.

Comment: @apalomer Thanks for your patient, but I'm really confused, if this algorithm can distinguish feature point and non-feature point, why I cannot visualize them in different color?

Comment: No, the FPFH algorithm will give a feature descriptor (i.e. `pcl::FPFHSignature33`) for each point in your point cloud. It does not matter if the point is belonging to a corner, a planer surface, or whatever. The algorithm will always give one descriptor per point, but the FPFH algorithm will not tell you what is an what is not a key point. For example, in my work that I cite earlier I use curvature on points prior to computing the FPFH, and then I only compute the FPFH for the points above a certain curvature.

Comment: @apalomer So the feature descriptor computed by FPFH is more like a multi-dimentional eigenvector or something ? and FPFH just describe each point in higher dimension. Is my understanding right? ps:Would you mind writing your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fast point feature histogram](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5152473) is a point descriptor (which in pcl comes in the form of `pcl::FPFHSignature33`). This means that the algorithm computes a histogram for all points in the input point cloud. Once the descriptors of the points are computed, then you can classify, segment... the points. But the process of classifying or segmenting the points would be another algorithm.

In [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/rob.21907) paper I use FPFH to coarsely align point clouds. In there I use the FPFH descriptors to decide which point from cloud A corresponds to which point from cloud B (associate points). In this publication, what I do is I compute the curvature for all points before the FPFH, and then, I only compute the FPFH of the subset of points that which curvature is above a given threshold. This is how I extract key points. Then, I use the FPFH of these key points fo the rest of the things (in my case associate points from different point clouds).

The analogy that you propose in one of your comments: "So the feature descriptor computed by FPFH is more like a multi-dimentional eigenvector or something " would be a good one.

So, to answer your question: No, there is no other tool apart from histograms to visualize the FPFH data (or at least not an out-of-the-box pcl class that you can use).

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks a lot !